# invalid operands of types 'double*' and 'double' to binary 'operator+'

Tags: c++

Here is my template class I am trying to implement:

```
#ifndef __ENCRYPTION_HEADER_INCLUDED__
#define __ENCRYPTION_HEADER_INCLUDED__

#include <iostream>  // in/out 
#include <fstream>   // file
#include <string>    // string
#include <sstream>   // string stream

using namespace std; // standard namespacing eliminates std:: from code


template <class mytemp>
class encryption 
{   
    public:

        mytemp * p;   

        encryption(); 

        mytemp encrypt_function (mytemp);
};


template <class mytemp>
encryption<mytemp>::encryption ()
{
    string line_in, file_name;
    mytemp input_value;

    cout << "input file name which contains encryption keys: " ;
    getline(cin, file_name);
    cout << '\n';   
    ifstream val_file (file_name.c_str());

    p = new mytemp[10];

    if (val_file.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(val_file, line_in))
        {
            istringstream line_out(line_in);
            line_out >> hex >> input_value;

            *p = input_value;
            p++;
        }

        p -= 10;
        val_file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "file not found" << '\n';
    }
}

template <class mytemp>
mytemp encryption<mytemp>::encrypt_function (mytemp input_en)
{
    mytemp output_en = input_en;

    for (mytemp k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        output_en ^= *(p + k); // does not work with double or float but works with int?
    }
    return output_en;
}

#endif // __ENCRYPTION_HEADER_INCLUDED__
```

the line shown below is the one I am having a problem with:

```
output_en ^= *(p + k); // does not work with double or float but works with int?
```

My understanding is that this is correct for an integer but it does not work for double or float and I am wondering if there is an easy way to get this to work other than rewriting the code to increment the pointer instead of incrementing through the pointed to values?

Comment: Side note: Never put a `using namespace std;``in a header

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you expect `operator+` on a `double*` and a `double` to do exactly? What is your expected result here?

Comment: Side note: You have too much documentation. Make the code readable with proper function and variable names,

Comment: I am trying to pass through the values stored using pointer p but not increment the pointer in the process so as to remove the need to reinitialize the pointer back to the start at the end of the function.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Wow, good job. At first the code was well-explained. Now it has no comments at all. Great teaching!

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic expects a *signed integer* (i.e, `std::ptrdiff_t`) type, which double or float are neither. In this loop here:

```
for (mytemp k = 0; k < 10; k++)
{
    output_en ^= *(p + k); // does not work with double or float but works with int?
}
```

It makes no sense to use a float or double. Just use a signed int (which `int` is).

Comment: the whole point to the design is that any type can be passed in and encrypted so it must be able to xor with a double or a float or any other type.

Comment: @Eamon116 but that is not what `k` is. That is an array index, not an array element. What is the 2.3rd element of an array?

Comment: The problem is that the code shouldn't be used for doubles and floats as they use extended precision so therefore a bit wise operator will not work as not all the bits used for representing the data are XOR'able due to some being used for an integer value and some used from the exponent. You solved the actually problem I ask for help with `std::ptrdiff_t` as this allowed me to use `k` with the pointer arithmetic operator `+`

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise xor isn't defined for those types.  If you're interpreting the inputs as just bits, then you should do what `memcpy()` or `memset()` do and just interpret them as an untyped array of bytes.  That is, your template wrapper could determine the address and size of the data and pass those to a function that xors a block of memory.

Comment: I realized this after I tried using 'std::ptrdiff_t' to define k. the problem is that the code shouldn't be used for doubles and floats as they use extended precision so therefore a bit wise operator will not work as not all the bits used for representing the data are XOR'able due to some being used for an integer value and some used from the exponent.